# java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Cannot load 32-bit SWT libraries on 64-bit JVM

Tags: java, eclipse, swt

I got this error:

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Cannot load 32-bit SWT libraries on 64-bit JVM
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.Library.loadLibrary(Library.java:177)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.Library.loadLibrary(Library.java:151)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.C.<clinit>(C.java:21)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.<clinit>(Widget.java:100)
    at
```

I found this link but it is not downloading the zip file
`https://archive.eclipse.org/eclipse/downloads/drops4/R-4.4-201406061215/`
`https://archive.eclipse.org/eclipse/downloads/drops4/R-4.4-201406061215/download.php?dropFile=eclipse-SDK-4.4-win32-x86_64.zip`

Where can I find the 64-bit libraries for 64-bit JVM?
Is it possible to run SWT libraries on 64-bit JVM?

Comment: Why are you trying to run Eclipse Luna (4.4) which is 9 years and 24 releases old?

Comment: The current versions of Eclipse available at https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/ are all 64 bit.

Comment: If you want to execute a historical Eclipse version you should also use a historical 32bit JRE/JDK version.

Answer (score 0):

assuming you are maintaining legacy application, you need to download 32-bit JDK, build your client projects with it and use it to run your app